# How to calculate confidence interval for autocorrelation- and cross correlation functions?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I would like to calculate the confidence interval for my autocorrelation function. Does this calculation differ in any way from the normal way of calculating confidence intervals? How would I calculate the CF for cross correlation between two time series?

Thank you for any help =)